# Arduino IDE upload error

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, library, ir, remote-control

I've recently been trying to make program using IRremote(library) in my Arduino IDE(v1.8.9), but whenever I hit the upload button this error message is returned

> Sketch uses 7514 bytes (23%) of program storage space. Maximum is
>   32256 bytes. Global variables use 415 bytes (20%) of dynamic memory,
>   leaving 1633 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
>
> avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0002
>
> 0x5d != 0x62 avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
>
> avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

I'm using **Arduino UNO R3**

This is the code I'm trying to run

```
    #include <IRremote.h>
int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop()
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results))
    {
     Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
     irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
    }
}
```

Also, every other code(not using the IRremote library) uploads just fine without any errors.

Comment: Is it a genuine Arduino or a cheap Chinese knock-off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be power/connection problem or somehow the bootloader has been damaged.
So

- Check power
- Check Connection

If there no problem found, then by using usbasp, avrisp, usbtinyisp, etc reflash the bootloader. I hope your problem will be solved.